# watch for changes in UI Bootstrap carusel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello i follow tutorial and create basic carousel using UI Bootstrap.
I want to track current item in order to change class in navigation, i found solution to use $watch to it, is there any better way to trace that change ?
My example code:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {

    var caruselCurrentItem = 1;
    caruselCurrentItem = $('.carousel-inner .active').index();
    caruselCurrentItem += 1;

    $('#ulTest li').removeClass('TEST');
    $('#ulTest li:nth-child('+caruselCurrentItem+')').addClass('TEST');


});
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a closer look at the $watch documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using $watch it is certainly not working the way you expect it to work. However, instead of checking for the active class in the DOM I'd rather check for the active field in the model:

```
// I assume your slides are in $scope.slides
$scope.$watch(function() {
    // This function returns the index of the active slide
    var activeSlides = $scope.slides.filter(function(x) { return x.active }); 
    return $scope.slides.indexOf(activeSlides[0]);
}, function(index) {
    // The index has changed. Now you can do something with it
});
```

Comment: This. You can see from the docs that there's an active property on the active slide: `ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active"`.

Comment: Ok i have my number of slide :) Now i want to add class to my element         `code`<ul id="ulTest"><li ng-repeat="slide in slides"><a href="#" ng-click="ChangeSlide($index)"><p>{{slide.text}}</p></a></li></ul>`code`

Comment: Ok i have it in template 'code'ng-class="{test:$index==caruselCurrentItem}